# addEventListener with inexplicable undefined method error

Tags: javascript, filereader

I couldn't find an answer to this problem I've been having.

```
function UploadBar() {
    this.reader = new FileReader();
    this.reader.addEventListener(
        "onloadstart"
        , function(evt) {alert("Hello World");}
        , false
    );
}
```

when I try to run this code it gives me an undefined_method_error in the javascript debugger in chrome. Could anyone be so kind as to tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reader` is not an element, so don't use `.addEventListener` Instead do the following.

```
function UploadBar() {
    this.reader = new FileReader();
    this.reader.onloadstart = function(e) { alert('Hello World') };  
}
```

Comment: Note: As FileReader inherits from EventTarget, all those events can also be listened for by using the addEventListener method. source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader. Although for some reason this method is not available in older Android browsers.