# ionic/angular FileReader error (addEventListener is not a function) occurs in ios simulator

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filereader, addeventlistener

I have the function below and it works fine with ionic serve, but i get "reader.addEventListener is not a function" when I'm trying to run the same code on ios simulator.
Could you help me, please, find out what is wrong?

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener(
      "load",
      () => {
        this.imageToShow = reader.result;
      },
      false
    );
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    };
  };
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using for fileReader ?

Comment: I do not use any plugin, it is a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: same issue for me , any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542573/7123439), the `reader` is not an element, so you should use `onload` in this case. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51533810/7123439) is an updated version, using the same method.

```
createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    this.imageToShow = reader.result;
  }
  if (image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
}
```