# Converting an image to binary in javascript using base64

Tags: javascript, base64, image-conversion

I have to convert an image to binary for storing it through IPFS and retrieve it again as a viewable image.

I should do this with javascript code. Does any body have any clear example of how to do this? Will Base64 help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made some research before posting? I'm pretty sure you can find something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 11):

Use File Reader:

```js
/******************for base 64 *****************************/
function uploadFile(inputElement) {
  var file = inputElement.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    console.log('Encoded Base 64 File String:', reader.result);
    
    /******************* for Binary ***********************/
    var data=(reader.result).split(',')[1];
     var binaryBlob = atob(data);
     console.log('Encoded Binary File String:', binaryBlob);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="uploadFile(this)" />
```